# Trying to create a generic, re usable function for set of different statuses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that I'm including on each line of my component that looks at and filters off of the returned number of records with a specific status and then takes the length of that array and displays it on the screen.

```
{props.locations.filter(x => x.details && x.details.status === "NEVER").length}
```

Currently there are only 3 separate statuses that a location could possibly have. Because of that, I'm trying to create a separate function that looks at whatever status is passed in instead of hard coding it for each line in my component. I recognize that this might be a really basic question, but does any have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nicest is to able to partially apply `status`, so lets put it as a first argument

```
const filter = status => locations => {
  return locations.filter(x => x.details && x.details.status === status).length;
}
```

Now we can make nice filters for every status

```
const neverFilter = filter('NEVER');
const progressFilter = filter('PROGRESS')
// and use it
const results = neverFilter(locations);
```

If you need it can be used also in one line, so its very flexible construct

```
const results = filter('NEVER')(locations);
```

PS. I didn't append any TS types as you did not put any in your question, but if u use TS, status should be some kind of union like `type Status = 'NEVER' | 'Other'`, and location should be kind of Record type. Just saying :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  filter = (locations, status) => {
     return locations.filter(x => x.details && x.details.status === status).length;
  }
```

And call the function:

```
this.filter(props.locations, 'NEVER');
```